# Pass user defined variable in function written in JSR223 Sampler

Tags: jmeter

How Can I pass User defined variable while calling function having parameters. (Function is created in JSR223 Sampler). And I need to call this function with user defined variable as parameter in next HTTP request as Server Name/IP/URL.

Comment: Please write a code sample

Answer (score 0):

- Put your Groovy code into `utility.groovy` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. If you want to use the different file - define `groovy.utilities` [JMeter property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) in *user.properties* file pointing to the file containing your Groovy function
- There is `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which can be used for accessing any [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) value so the variable can be read as `vars.get('variable-name')`
- You can call your function using [__groovy() JMeter Function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

  ```
   ${__groovy(your-function-here(vars.get('your-variable-here'),)}
  ```

More information: [Advanced Groovy Scripting configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#groovy)